# How to convert a PDF document to an array on my Angular webapp (Client Side)

Tags: angular

I have an Angular web application. I want to covert PDF documents to array, but I want to do this on the client side. Most packages that exist seem to work only for Node.js servers.

Wondering if anyone can help. For reference, the document is basically a table showing data row by row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pdf.js` to accomplish this. Refer the below stps for reference:

Install pdf.js

```
npm install pdfjs-dist
```

Import it to your angular component like the below:

```
import * as pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf';


pdfUrl = 'path/to/your/document.pdf'; // replace with you pdf file path

ngOnInit() {
  this.convertPDFToArray(this.pdfUrl)
       .then((textArray) => {
        console.log('PDF converted to array:', textArray);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
       console.error('Error converting PDF:', error);
   });
}

convertPDFToArray(pdfUrl: string): Promise<any[]> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const loadingTask = pdfjs.getDocument(pdfUrl);

    loadingTask.promise.then((pdfDocument: any) => {
      const numPages = pdfDocument.numPages;
      const promises = [];

      for (let pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= numPages; pageNumber++) {
        const page = pdfDocument.getPage(pageNumber);
        promises.push(page.then((pdfPage: any) => pdfPage.getTextContent()));
      }

      Promise.all(promises)
        .then((pageContents: any[]) => {
          const textArray = [];

          for (const content of pageContents) {
            for (const item of content.items) {
              textArray.push(item.str);
            }
          }

          resolve(textArray);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I am trying to implement it but get the following error: 

Error: Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)

Comment: Just add this to the module.exports object in webpack.config.js file. `experiments: {
  topLevelAwait: true
}`

Comment: I don't have a webpack file but a angular.json file. Where it doens't allow expeiments to be added